# Is connection pool shared across application

Tags: c#, ado.net

In ADO.net application we have a website and windows service which are hitting same database. Since the connection string is common between them so are they sharing same connection pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, basically. The pool is per-process. It might even be per app-domain, but since it uses an unmanaged driver underneath, I'm not *100%* sure.

Comment: It's documented - at least for [SQLClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) - "Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity."