# C# Connection pool issue: The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-pooling, ormlite-servicestack

`OrmLiteConnectionFactory` is responsible for creating a new `SqlConnection`.
`MaxConnectionPoolSize = 100`. `PoolSize < 50`.

Code that creates a new connection:

```
services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>((IDbConnectionFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(OrmLiteConnectionFactory), connectionString));
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>((provider) =>
            {
                var factory = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionFactory>();
                var connection = factory.OpenDbConnection();
                return connection;
            });
```

Sometimes while opening a new connection `SqlClient` throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Call Stack:

```
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnection.Open()
```

So, the max connection pool size is not reached but a new connection can't be established.
Really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` creates `SqlConnection`(see call stack). So this is common ADO .Net connection pool

Comment: Keep in mind that not all database people can read and properly interpret a call stack. My other questions are still valid, lots of applications use `SqlConnection` and do terrible, terrible things with them.

Comment: @AaronBertrand an opened connection could live from 1 to 5 sec, in average 3sec. The app is written in the way to have up to 64 open connection in a moment of a time.

Comment: @BasilKosovan do you close /dispose connections explicitly or rely on GC?

Comment: @alexm IOC container is responsible for closing connection

Comment: @BasilKosovan Do you constantly observe the pool size ? You could have reached the maximal number for a few seconds.  Performance counters could come up handy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @alexm can’t use counters with .net6, it works only for .netframework

Comment: For .net core and .net 5 and up consider using dotnet-counters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters
here is the list of counters for SQL client:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/event-counters?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @alexm this package works only for .net core3.1. I see that there is another package for .Net6. Will try to use it

Comment: Please share the code that opens a connection through OrmLiteConnectionFactory.

Comment: @labilbe added to the Q

Answer (score 1):

What you must do every time your app does db work is to make sure that **SqlDataReaders**, **SqlCommand**, **SqlConnection** objects are closed and disposed of as soon as possible.  The easiest way to do that is to use the *Using* keyword on objects that implement *IDisposable*.  Otherwise, these types of objects remain in memory until the garbage collector gets around to destroying them.  Check source code in your entire app to implement the above method.

I had to do this when the exact same issue reared its head when my company's customers were calling our APIs!

Comment: I agree with you 100% but as long as we don't go over the limit we shouldn't have exceptions

Answer (score 0):

The connection pool is machine wide. Are there other apps or processes running that use database connections?
Maybe your SQL Server has a 'max worker threads' limit?

Otherwise an answer is to look at why so many connections are in use for so long. Maybe the connections can be released earlier.

Comment: max_workers_count=512, this exception can happen if a number of active connection is 4

Comment: I don't believe this answer is accurate. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538883/) and its first comment which points to [docs for ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling), "Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity."

Comment: @Johann the post you linked has little to do with my answer, which is about how connections are limited, not how they're pooled. Connection limit is obviously machine wide. I can see how you can read my answer as meaning connections are globally pooled, but a per-application pool is just a logical division inside the connection pool of which there is only one instance per machine.

Comment: @Simmetric it may be true that the SQL Server has a machine-wide connection limit, and it may also be true that the client has a connection limit (likely the TCP connection limit imposed by the OS), but this question is about neither, and your answer specifically stated that the "connection pool is machine wide". The connection pool is NOT machine wide, and there are multiple instances of the ADO.NET connection pool; from the doc linked previous: "ADO.NET keeps several pools at the same time, one for each configuration."